# Android app fails to load native library code on 2.2

Tags: android, android-ndk

Working on an app that has a shared code library build in C++ (NDK), Android 2.2 cannot load the library.

When I go to a certain view it needs to load the results that it gets from the .so native library, it works on 2.3+ but on 2.2 the app just goes to a black screen. I figured that it's dying during the process of loading native code, but not sure what's happening.

For example: on 2.3 the ADT verbose output looks like this:

> 04-15 11:49:07.210: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26048): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.app.myapp/lib/libViewer.so 0x4051b858

04-15 11:49:07.220: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26048): Added shared lib /data/data/com.app.myapp/lib/libViewer.so 0x4051b858

but on 2.2. it just stays at:

> 04-15 11:56:27.123: DEBUG/dalvikvm(275): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.app.myapp/lib/libViewer.so 0x45f3dc28

and it just sits here...

Has anyone come across any problems like this?

From Java's code perspective it freezes on the line:

```
static {
     System.loadLibrary("nativeViewer");//<-- goes into neverland here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when compiling with gcc 4.7.  When I changed back to using the default compiler, gcc 4.6, I no longer had the issue you described.  I looked through the ndk documentation and never saw anything about gcc 4.7 not working on android 2.2 and older but they do say that gcc 4.7 is experimental.

Comment: David, thank you for your reply. It looks like recompiling with 4.6 did solve the issue. I am now able to go into the application without going to neverland.